# SSH not working outside of local machine

Tags: ssh, openssh

So, I'm trying to learn SSH. I don't have a public IPv4 address. So, I'm using my IPv6 address but SSH is only working inside my local machine. When I try it with WSL, it is showing

```
ssh: connect to host 2402:d000:8100:184:5fc5:e97a:2850:c8a9 port 22: Network is unreachable.
```

This is my public IPv6 address. What do I do?

Comment: Is the WSL system the one with this public ipv6 address? If not, does it also have an ipv6 address and is there a route between them? The topology of what you've got isn't clear. Can you add the information to your question

Comment: Are you running the ssh command on your wsl machine? If not what are you running it on?